# $dirty in angularjs remains true after removing the changes

Tags: angularjs

I am using $dirty to check the changes in a form ,but if i type something in the input box and remove it, the $dirty is still true.Is there any solution or it will work like this.

Comment: Yes. $dirty will be true. You can set it $pristine using JS

Comment: $pristine also wont change until u reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is by design. Any form becomes `$dirty` whenever the user interacts with it, and you cannot *undo* the interaction event. Though you can restore defaults, that is clearly not the same.

Consider using `$watch` to check whether new value is different from the default one, and `$setPristine()` to clear user input.

Comment: But for setting watch i have to give watch in each and evry function , directive wont work for all the pages, Do you have any solution for making a global directive that works for each Page having different models . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$dirty means The field has been modified one more time. for compare your model by your previous model you can use `$watch` in controller.
if your field is empty you have a solution must set required attribute and  in your input tag and use below code set ng-validate of your form to novalidate and then use below code for compare:

```
formName.inputName.$dirty && formName.inputName.$error.required
```